# Оператор in >> в собственном классе строк

Tags: c++

Реализовал класс строк, и сделал оператор >> , когда ввожу строчку с пробелами , например а а. аыаыв аы, то выводит только первый символ, то бишь 'а' , попытался сделать с temp , как показано ниже

```
istream& operator >> (istream& in, const String &ob) {
    String temp;
    temp.string = ob.string;
    in >> temp.string;
    return in;
}
```

Стал выдавать ошибку malloc: *** error for object 0x10051b2c0: pointer being freed was not allocated, компилятор указывает на деструктор 
Вот что написал в main

```
int main() {
    String a, b("Jaaasfg"), c ("Sb af bd");
    a = b;
    cout << a << endl;
    a = c ;
    cin >> a;
    cout << a;
    a = c;
    cout << a;
    return 0;
```

Вот всё описание класса:

```
String :: String (const char *str) {
    size = strlen(str) +1;
    string = new char [size];
    strcpy (string, str);
}

String :: String (const String &ob) {
    size = strlen(ob.string) +1;
    string = new char [size];
    strcpy (string, ob.string);
}

String :: ~String () {    delete [] string;
}

void String :: show () {
    cout << string << endl;
}

String String :: operator = (const String &ob) {
    if (string)
        delete [] string;
    size = strlen(ob.string) + 1;
    string = new char [size];
    strcpy(string,ob.string);
    return *this;
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& out , const String &ob) {
    out << ob.string;
    return out;

}
istream& operator >> (istream& in, const String &ob) {
    String temp;
    temp.string = ob.string;
    in >> temp.string;
    return in;
}
```

Определение класса:

```
#ifndef String_h
#define String_h

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class String {
    int size;
    char *string;
public:
    String (const char *str = "");
    String (const String &ob);
    ~String ();
    void show ();
    String operator = (const String &ob);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out , const String &ob);
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, const String &ob);



};

#endif /* String_hpp */
```

Comment: Идите читайте про [mcve].

Comment: Я поправил, можете посмотреть?

Comment: Добавьте определение `class String`. В идеале нужен такой код, который можно сразу скопилировать (не добавляя инклуды и т.п.).

Comment: У вас нет конструктора  по умолчанию, однако вы пытаетесь создавать  обьект   `String` `a`, и дальше работаете с ним. Это уже одна большая ошибка

Comment: String (const char *str = ""); так разве это не заменяет конструктор по умолчанию? Ведь я задаю значение str = ""

Comment: да, но в определении конструктора этого нет

Comment: ```String :: String (const char *str) {
    size = strlen(str) +1;
    string = new char [size];
    strcpy (string, str);
}``` а это не то?

Comment: Очевидно что в `temp.string = ob.string;` приходит присваивание указателя на буфер, которым владеет другой объект. Кроме того, `operator >>` у вас почему-то принимает ссылку на объект с const квалификатором. ще надо позаботиться, чтобы в буфере было достаточно места для записи, а у вас это никак не контрлируется

Comment: Если в  ```operator >>``` я уберу const , то тогда я не смогу использовать string у своего объекта

Comment: Если у объекта будет const квалификатор, то он не может (не должен) быть изменен внутри оператора >>

Comment: как тогда мне реализовать этот оператор, чтобы можно было вводить значение в string?

Comment: посмотрите как реализован этот оператор для std::string

Answer (score 0):

Я оставил те части кода, где исправлены ошибки.

```
class String {
   //...
    String& operator = (const String& ob);
    //...
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& in,  String& ob);
};
String::String(const char* str = "") {
    //...
}
//...

String& String::operator = (const String& ob) {
    //...
}

//...
istream& operator >> (istream& in,  String& ob) {     
    in >> ob.string;
    ob.size = strlen(ob.string) + 1;//можно без этого
    //в идеале нужно выделять новую память, если вводимых символов больше
    return in;
}
```

Чтобы долго не обяснять, сами смотрите и сравнивайте.

P.S., для символьных строк можно определить метод, возвращающий размер, и не придется хранить размер `size`.